# How to use only one ADC channel on MAX10

Tags: fpga, quartus

I have an ADC core

```
component adc_qsys is
port (
    adc_1_command_valid          : in  std_logic                     := '0';              
    adc_1_command_channel        : in  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0)  := (others => '0');            
    adc_1_command_startofpacket  : in  std_logic                     := '0';            
    adc_1_command_endofpacket    : in  std_logic                     := '0';            
    adc_1_command_ready          : out std_logic;                                        
    adc_1_response_valid         : out std_logic;                                        
    adc_1_response_channel       : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);                    
    adc_1_response_data          : out std_logic_vector(11 downto 0);                    
    adc_1_response_startofpacket : out std_logic;                                        
    adc_1_response_endofpacket   : out std_logic;                                     
    clk_clk                      : in  std_logic                     := '0';             
    reset_reset_n                : in  std_logic                     := '0'              
);
end component adc_qsys;

U_ADC_SYS : adc_qsys 
port map 
(
    clk_clk        => s_pll_clk_10M, 
    reset_reset_n  => '1', 

    adc_1_command_valid          => adc1_com_valid, 
    adc_1_command_channel        => adc1_com_channel, 
    adc_1_command_startofpacket  => adc1_com_startofpacket,
    adc_1_command_endofpacket    => adc1_com_endofpacket, 
    adc_1_command_ready          => adc1_com_ready,
    adc_1_response_valid         => adc1_resp_valid,
    adc_1_response_channel       => adc1_resp_channel,
    adc_1_response_data          => adc1_resp_data, 
    adc_1_response_startofpacket => adc1_resp_startofpacket,
    adc_1_response_endofpacket   => adc1_resp_endofpacket
);
```

When I used the whole port ADC1_IN1 - ADC1_IN8 was no problem.
Now I want to use only one channel - ADC1_IN1 so I set only CH1 active in the core.

[image: adc]

However I get the errors while compiling

> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_7 (IOPAD_X0_Y37_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_CMD[5] is assigned to pin location Pin_7 (IOPAD_X0_Y37_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN2~ is assigned to pin location Pin_7 (IOPAD_X0_Y37_N21)
> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_8 (IOPAD_X0_Y36_N14)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_CMD[6] is assigned to pin location Pin_8 (IOPAD_X0_Y36_N14)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN3~ is assigned to pin location Pin_8 (IOPAD_X0_Y36_N14)
> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_10 (IOPAD_X0_Y36_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_CMD[7] is assigned to pin location Pin_10 (IOPAD_X0_Y36_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN4~ is assigned to pin location Pin_10 (IOPAD_X0_Y36_N21)
> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_11 (IOPAD_X0_Y35_N14)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_CMD[8] is assigned to pin location Pin_11 (IOPAD_X0_Y35_N14)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN5~ is assigned to pin location Pin_11 (IOPAD_X0_Y35_N14)
> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_12 (IOPAD_X0_Y35_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_CMD[9] is assigned to pin location Pin_12 (IOPAD_X0_Y35_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN6~ is assigned to pin location Pin_12 (IOPAD_X0_Y35_N21)
> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_13 (IOPAD_X0_Y34_N14)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_TEST is assigned to pin location Pin_13 (IOPAD_X0_Y34_N14)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN7~ is assigned to pin location Pin_13 (IOPAD_X0_Y34_N14)
> Error (176310): Can't place multiple pins assigned to pin location Pin_14 (IOPAD_X0_Y34_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin LED_FLTn is assigned to pin location Pin_14 (IOPAD_X0_Y34_N21)
> Info (176311): Pin ~ALTERA_ADC1IN8~ is assigned to pin location Pin_14 (IOPAD_X0_Y34_N21)

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Well.. I found the answer - If you use bank 1A for ADC, you cannot use the bank for GPIO.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you have a second module which has ports LED_CMD and LED_TEST that are using the same FPGA outputs. Take a look at your constraints/IO placement and move the other module to some other pins. That should fix it.

You could use the same bank for 2 different modules assuming the outputs are the same IO spec (LVCMOS33 etc.) as long as multiple outputs don't map to the same pin. Especially here, if you're only using 1 channel of the ADC, there's no reason for the other pins in the bank to not be used.

Comment: As I was told -  If you use bank 1A for ADC, you cannot use the bank for GPIO. It's all or none.

Comment: Not necessarily. There's no reason why multiple modules, blocks or components can't share an IO bank if they use the same IO standard. You'd just need to ensure the total ports (ADC + GPIO) are less than or equal to the total pins in that bank.

Comment: As I understood they can not combine ADC and GPIO functionality in the same (ADC1) bank. That what official data sheet says.